# How to get css class from image tag on button tap Sencha Touch?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I’ve added an image tag in ListView in itemTpl as follows:

```
<img src='/maxtouch/images/close.png' alt='close' id='imgFavClose' class='close-favlist' />
```

Now I want to remove the css class 'close-favlist' from image on button tap event. To remove the css class I’ve written following line of code:

```
 var favList = Ext.getCmp('favList'),
 imgClose = favList.down('#imgFavClose');
 imgClose.removeCls('close-favlist');
```

***Here favList is id of ListView.***

But it does not work. Plz let me know what correct way to perform this task.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Hi Arun. Make it a habit to accept the answers if you were able to use the suggestions. It is the best way to reward the person who has put lots of effort to find a solution for your problem.

Comment: Is there only one #imgFavClose in the whole list ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Ext.select('#imgFavClose').removeCls('close-favlist');
```

Check the `docs` on [select](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext-method-select)